# basic calculus inequality

Tags: calculus

Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove this inequality? I've tried various algebraic manipulations with exponentiation, but I haven't gotten anywhere. Thanks!

$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \ln(f(x))dx\leq \ln(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx)$

Comment: Notice that $\ln(x)$ is concave.

Comment: hint: when is $\ln(x) < x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directly follows from Jensen's Inequality, which says that if $g$ is a concave function; than $E[g(f(X))] \leq g(E[f(X)])$ for any function $f$ with finite expectations ($X$ denote random variable and $E[\cdot]$ denotes expectation). In your case, $g$ is $ln$, which is concave (and Jensen's Inequality is applied assuming a uniform distribution).

Jensen's Inequality on the other hand is a generalization of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. You can check it out here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This problem was given to me as "something fun to think about," but I've never heard of Jensen's Inequality, so I probably wouldn't have been able to solve it.